# Do I have a wire to repurpose as a C-wire?

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

Do I have a wire to repurpose as a C-wire??[image]

Comment: It looks like your white wire is not actually in the cable, and runs separately into the wall? That may imply that you can pull more cable here without too much trouble.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at your furnace/air-handler please, or a wiring diagram of said furnace/air-handler for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

If you have heating, cooling, and fan modes of operation, and no additional wires in the cable, looks like all the wires are spoken for.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that a separate wire was run outside the original cable (likely to add air conditioning) so unless there's something I'm missing in the photo there's no wire available for reuse as a C-wire.  I see a connection for a C-wire that is not used, indicating that if there was a C-wire available before then it would likely have already been used.  Are you looking to make that connection for this thermostat or a new one?  Some thermostats have optional adapters for getting that extra C-wire with the wires you have, is there any indication this is an option?  I assume you already looked but there is no indication of that.

I've heard of rare exceptions in which, maybe, possibly, with odd installations, the fan (or "G" for green) wire can be reused but this means losing the ability to turn the fan on (as opposed to "auto") from the thermostat.  The opposite is more common, that the fan *MUST* be controlled by the thermostat rather than being an optional convenience to turn it on manually.

If there's been an added wire run already then it must not be terribly difficult to run one more wire.  Anything preventing that?

There's options, and it is up to a matter of opinion on which is best.